# What is the proper way to read from Java sockets?

Tags: java, sockets

I have a simple TCP server that communicates on text-based protocol. I'm receiving data from clients and then I send an OK/NOT OK response.

The protocol has this format:

`<KEYWORD> <DATA>\r\n`

`<KEYWORD>` ascii text, no limits on length, just that it is atleast 1.

`<DATA>` mostly just ascii text, can be binary data, in that case, lenght is send first (to allow for \r\n sequence inside)

every command ends in \r\n and there is always space between `<KEYWORD>` and `<DATA>`

I tried reading byte by byte, e.g.:

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
InputStream is = socket.getInputStream();    
while (tmp != ' '){
    baos.write(in.read());
}
```

However I ran into a problem that `in.read()` returns -1 if it didn't read anything and my `ByteArrayOutputStream` was getting flooded with -1s (and not just -1, in debugging I saw -3, -32, 3 and so on). My solution was to wrap it in `if`, like this:

```
while (tmp != ' '){
    byte tmp = in.read();
    if(tmp >= 'A' && tmp <='z'){
        baos.write(tmp);
    }
}
```

but that doesn't seem like a proper way to do this, since this also reads anything between uppercase and lowercase letters. What if I decide to exclude `^` and `_`, then I have to add `&& tmp != '^' && tmp != '_'`.

Can someone point me towards the right way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `InputStream.read()` returns an ***int*** not a `byte`.  This is so that -1 can be distinguished from the bit pattern 0x11111111, which is also a signed byte -1.  You should be using

```
int tmp = in.read();
```

So you can differentiate the two values.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you read line-by-line, given you expect a text stream?

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
String line = null;
while((line = br.readLine())!= null){ /* TODO */ }
```

Of course, handling in the same socket both text command and binary data will give you some headache. For example, FTP use two ports.

You can send base64-encoded binary data, as they do on textual procotols that can handle binary data (HTTP, SMTP ecc)

Answer (score 0):

You should read until the stream ends, which is signified by -1.
Use an ignore string to easily filter out characters

```
String ignore = "_^";
int data = in.read();
while (data != -1) {
    if (ignore.indexOf((char)data) != -1)
        baos.write(data);
    data = in.read());
}
```

Note for performance reasons you should be using buffered reads.  See InputStream.read(byte[]).